# mysql query to get data from various time periods

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
        COUNT(t1.tid) AS count,
        u.user_name,
        SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.endtime)))/COUNT(t1.endtime)) AS `avg`,
        MAX(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `max`,
        MIN(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `min`,
        CONCAT(
            IF(t1.starttime>=(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE), '15', ''),
            IF(t1.starttime>=(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE), '30', ''),
            IF(t1.starttime>=(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR), 'H', ''),
            IF(t1.starttime>=(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'D', ''),
            IF(t1.starttime>=DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d'), 'W', ''),
            IF(t1.starttime>=CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE), 'M', '')
        ) AS period,
        t1.starttime
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` u ON u.id = t1.user_id
    WHERE t1.starttime >= CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
    GROUP BY user_name, period
```

The above is a sample query that I have done. My intention is to get results for various time lines. ie get count, min, max etc for last 15mins, 1 hour, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month etc.

So what I want is the result to be like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| period       | count        | user            | min          | max             |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   15mins     |   12         |   test_user1    |   00:00:45   |    00:01:45     |
|   15mins     |   12         |   test_user2    |   00:00:45   |    00:01:45     |
|   15mins     |   12         |   test_user3    |   00:00:45   |    00:01:45     |
|   15mins     |   12         |   test_user4    |   00:00:45   |    00:01:45     |
|   15mins     |   12         |   test_user5    |   00:00:45   |    00:01:45     |
|   30mins     |   15         |   test_user1    |   00:01:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   30mins     |   15         |   test_user2    |   00:01:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   30mins     |   16         |   test_user3    |   00:04:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   30mins     |   18         |   test_user4    |   00:09:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   30mins     |   19         |   test_user10   |   00:07:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   30mins     |   14         |   test_user11   |   00:04:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   30mins     |   15         |   test_user12   |   00:00:45   |    00:11:45     |
|   1day       |   100        |   test_user1    |   01:00:45   |    01:11:45     |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

t1.starttime is the datetime. And we get the results based on the current server time.

Answer (score 0):

If your intervals are nested (15 min in 30 min in 1 hour etc) then you can't avoid unions and your query (which I simplified a bit) will look like this:

```
select count(t1.tid) as count, '15 min' period, userid ,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.endtime)))/COUNT(t1.endtime)) AS `avg`,
        MAX(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `max`,
        MIN(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `min`

from t1
where timestampdiff(minute,t1.starttime,now()) < 15 
group by userid
UNION
select count(t1.tid) as count, '30 min' , userid ,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.endtime)))/COUNT(t1.endtime)) AS `avg`,
        MAX(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `max`,
        MIN(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `min`

from t1
where timestampdiff(minute,t1.starttime,now()) < 30 
group by userid
UNION
select count(t1.tid) as count, '60 min', userid ,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.endtime)))/COUNT(t1.endtime)) AS `avg`,
        MAX(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `max`,
        MIN(TIMEDIFF(t1.endtime,t1.starttime)) AS `min`

from t1
where timestampdiff(minute,t1.starttime,now()) < 60 
group by userid
/* and so on */
order by period, userid
```

Comment: Are you sure that this cant be done without UNION?

Can adding period to GROUP BY yield the correct result? 

Currently the PHP coded executes different queries and combines the results (which is slow). So im trying to do all in a single query without unions

Comment: Actually a union query is single and runs within the same transaction. And it's not php, it's a pure mysql query. The query cannot be constructed w/o unions because you can't generate 2 lines from a single row for the same columns. And there's no need to group by period cause every part has the same period value, so it's initially grouped.

Comment: I was referring to grouping by period in my query. I understand your sub queries have the same period.

I tried the UNION query and it takes a good 7 seconds to complete. Almost similar to the current setup.

Comment: How many records do you have in your table? If you're not fully satisfied with the time taken, use cursors -- they will be much more rapid.